# no output of xslt transformation cause of used namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, namespaces

i have an xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0">
  <entry>
    <g:id>1207</g:id>
    <g:price>25.90 EUR</g:price>
  </entry>
 </feed>
```

and i want to create an csv output of the data with the following xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">id;price       
        <xsl:for-each select="feed/entry">
            <xsl:value-of select="g:id"/>;<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I required the following output, but only the headline is printed out

```
id;title       
1207;25.90 EUR
```

I suppose that something with the namespace is the reason for the missing data, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, and there are hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow addressing precisely this problem, try searching for something like "xslt default namespace".

Comment: @Ian, thats the reason why i asked here, i haven't found something really helpful for me. I have spent a lot of time to search for a solution but in the end i got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose that something with the namespace is the reason for the
>   missing data

Yes, that is correct. Your stylesheet ignores the fact that `<feed>` and `<entry>` have their own namespace. You have incorrectly declared this namespace in your stylesheet as the default namespace. Try instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">id;price       
    <xsl:for-each select="a:feed/a:entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="g:id"/>;<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

Of course, to get the output in the form you require, the template needs to look more like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>id;price&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="a:feed/a:entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="g:id"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="g:price"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help, because of your example. I see much clearer now of using namesspaces in xml transformations